# How to calculate inner surface area with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

[image: visual of the problem]

Hello! One of the practice problems for my upcoming test was this problem. I think I have a pretty good understanding of how to calculate the surface area with integrals, but this problem completely threw me off. I only had two possible ideas, but I honestly have no idea where to go from here. Also, I asked my teacher and he just told me to make the segment between (-70, -16) linear. I didn't really know where to go from there.

I have an idea! If (-70,-16) is a line, you could break the dam wall into two parts; an upper and a lower. the upper part would be a perfect cylinder, so you wouldn't need to make an integral. I'm still stuck on the lower part.
I'm honestly just really lost, but I'm trying to learn! I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: For the lower part, the radius at the base is smallest and keeps increasing till you get to $(-16, 244)$. As you are supposed to consider the edge from $(-70, 0)$ to $(-16, 244)$ a straight line, it is not difficult to come up with radius in terms of height. Then it is just integrating to find surface area.